# VS2015 CodeLens missing after update

Tags: visual-studio

Only just noticed it. The 'heading' that showed how many references a method has had gone missing. I assume after the last update that I installed. I didn't even know it was called Codelens but now I am wiser.
As per other answer in S.O. It is an option under Tool-> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens. The update (I assume) had disabled it)
HTH someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the option Tool-> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens and enable it.